What type of rounding is used during token allocation calculation?
I have an issue during smart contract research. I could not verify how I should calculate my token allocation for a swap.
This is the contract on Base. The contract has a method buyExactShares, which I use for buying a token allocation. One of the parameters is tokenAllocation.
Here is a case: I am buying tokens in USDC that is 10^6. Token that I try to buy is in 10^18. I fetch the token price in USDC by calling assetsPerToken. The platform fee is 2%. So the calculation should be straightforward:
Amount of USDC / Price per token / 1.02 (Fee)

But when I try to conduct calculations, I receive a different value. For example:
1 / 0.00875 / 1.02 = 112.04481792717085 

But the contract expects 112.044705882352941142. I use Python3 for calculations.
Could you please explain how I can achieve the expected rounding for this contract?

During token allocation calculations, rounding down (floor rounding) is typically used to ensure no extra tokens are distributed beyond the total supply. This approach prioritizes fairness and prevents overallocation.
